# getting "defined" modules from a CPAN dist file?

Tags: perl, cpan

Given a CPAN dist file (e.g. like `Acme-Chef-1.01.tar.gz`), what is the algorithm to determine what module-versions are "defined" (or present) in the dist file?

For instance, in the `02packages.details.txt` file, there are four lines which correspond to this dist file:

```
Acme::Chef                         1.01  S/SM/SMUELLER/Acme-Chef-1.01.tar.gz
Acme::Chef::Container              1.00  S/SM/SMUELLER/Acme-Chef-1.01.tar.gz
Acme::Chef::Ingredient             1.00  S/SM/SMUELLER/Acme-Chef-1.01.tar.gz
Acme::Chef::Recipe                 1.00  S/SM/SMUELLER/Acme-Chef-1.01.tar.gz
```

I basically want to know how those lines are generated.

Is the procedure something like:

1. find all of the `.pm` files in the dist file
2. load each of the `.pm` files and print out `${ "${pkg}::VERSION"}` where `$pkg` is the package name corresponding to the `.pm` file name (i.e. if the `.pm` file name is `Foo/Bar.pm` then `$pkg` is `Foo::Bar`.)

Is there code which does this indexing procedure?

Do you really have to load the module in order to determine what its version is?

Comment: It doesn't execute the module; just the line containing $VERSION

Comment: Have you see [About PAUSE](http://pause.perl.org/pause/query?ACTION=pause_04about)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual code that does it for PAUSE is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/andk/pause). The subroutines that parse package and version declarations are in lib/PAUSE/pmfile.pm (`packages_per_pmfile` and `parse_version`). This is authoritative as far as what happens to make CPAN work, but it's not code that you'd ever want to use for yourself — PAUSE is almost 20 years old and even after some recent cleanup it's still pretty gross.

Instead, look at [Module::Metadata](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aMetadata). You give it a file, and it provides a pretty simple interface to discover the names of the packages inside of that file and what their versions might be.

It's about as simple as:

```
my $mm = Module::Metadata->new_from_file("My/Module.pm");
for my $package ($mm->packages_inside) {
    print "$package: ", $mm->version($package), "\n";
}
```

And indeed this "one-liner" works:

```
find Acme-Chef-1.01 -name \*.pm \
| perl -MModule::Metadata -ln \
-e 'my $mm = Module::Metadata->new_from_file($_); ' \
-e 'print "$_: ", $mm->version($_) for $mm->packages_inside' \
| sort
```

and outputs:

```
Acme::Chef: 1.01
Acme::Chef::Container: 1.00
Acme::Chef::Ingredient: 1.00
Acme::Chef::Recipe: 1.00
```

Comment: There is also [Dist::Metadata](http://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Metadata) which is (mostly) just a wrapper around `Module::Metadata.`  Depending on your needs, `Dist::Metadata` might have a more agreeable interface.  But beware that none of these tools will always produce an index **exactly** like PAUSE.  Aside from subtle differences in the implementation, the current PAUSE index is dependent on all the distributions that were indexed previously.  But in most cases, `Module::Metadata` is good enough.  That's what [Pinto](http://metacpan.org/module/Pinto) uses.